# How should I go about designing a custom dropdown in android like Feedly app?

Tags: android, drop-down-menu

The default dropdown spinner available in android is a like a list. Would like to know exactly how could I implement a custom dropdown as implemented in the Feedly android application. Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jVVQ.png

Comment: May the [Google](http://www.google.com) be with you!

Comment: Could not find any thing online...

Comment: In this case, you need a tutorial on how to use [Google](http://www.google.com/)